# How to delete multiple files from multiple folders in batch

Tags: batch-file

I was trying to make a batch file that could copy a whole folder (with files and subfolders) inside multiple subfolders placed inside multiple subfolders.
The fact is that I messed up the commands and ended with all the files and subfolders copied where I wanted but not inside a folder.

Now I want to delete all these files and subfolders without deleting the original files from each folder.

I tried this command directly in a command prompt window, but it didn't work and I have no idea why because the input and the loops appear to be right.

```
for /d %a in (`E:\Mis documentos\Nueva carpeta\Filosofia\*') do for /d %b in ("%a\*") do for %c in ("*") do del %b\%c
```

This returns "The system cannot find the specified file" but the command executed is `del E:\Mis documentos\Nueva carpeta\Filosofia\Some folder\Another folder\The exact file` that I want to delete in that folder. What could cause that?

When I do the same but echoing %b/%c it returns the exact path of the items I want to delete from the folders. (Note that I am trying to run this command from inside the folder I wanted to copy in the first place so that I can recover the name of each file independently.)

Comment: `del "c:\somefolder\*.txt" "c:\somefolder\*.exe" /s`

Comment: `For` loops in batch files require %%A rather than %A at command prompt.

Comment: I forgot to explain that, the code in the post was executed in the command prompt for testing (thats why i use wrote a sinlge % each time), but it returns "The system can not find the specified file" but the command executed is del E:\Mis documentos\Nueva carpeta\Filosofia\Some folder\Another folder\The exact file that i want to delete in that folder. 
What i cant understand is why it doesnt finds the files.

Comment: You need to quote paths with spaces. But `del` is easier than `for`.

Comment: Thank you very much, i totally missed it! I must look like an idiot!

Comment: Asterisks have a special effect. To highlight code, prefix it with four spaces (or select it and use the `{}` toolbar symbol) - that way a code asterisk is reproduced verbatim. Within text, text between single asterisks beomes *italic* and between double becomes **bold**.

Comment: Also : `ECHO del` can be used to simply `echo` the `del` command - and that avoids potential damege when the command is processed in an unexpected manner. Same comment for `ren` or `(x)copy` or `move` - you can see the command without executing it. In fact, `ECHO(` is a better choice than `ECHO ` - the `(` plays no part in (parenthesised statement sequences)` but if the argument to the `echo` evaluates to *nothing* then `echo(` will show a newline, but `ECHO ` will report `ECHO is ON/OFF`.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to use the command `del` with the switches `/Q` (quiet) and `/S` (also in all subdirectories) as [D.Ddgg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3844141/d-ddgg) suggested already, too.

```
del /Q /S "E:\Mis documentos\Nueva carpeta\Filosofia\*.txt" "E:\Mis documentos\Nueva carpeta\Filosofia\*.jpg"
```

Arguments with a `space` or other special characters like `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ `` inside must be enclosed by double quotes. This list of special characters is output on running in a command prompt window `cmd /?` and looking on last paragraph on last page of the help.